# Change the Animation Start Option of all slides

Tags: animation, onclick, powerpoint, slide

i have a Powerpoint with 300 slides and all objects in all slides have the same start "on click" option.

i want to change this option and make every objects show at the same time IN ALL SLIDES. ("with previous").

does anybody know a fast way to do it?

Comment: Is there a slide template you can edit?

Comment: @TannerBabcock no, but i can change the template if i have to.